# HTML5 Form validation with javascript basket validation combined?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forum

I'm working on this sample request forum which works with a basket, I've validated it by tweaking the form so that it uses HTML5 validation, that works dandy. But prior to changing the "a submit" button to an "input button", it used to stop the form submission if the basket had more than 5 items in it by using this:

```
<a href="javascript:closeFiveCheck();"> BUTTON </a>
```

So now it validates the form but will let you submit the request with more than 5 items, which we don't want, and if i change it back to the anchor link, the html5 fourm won't work, so I need a way to combine the two.

Here is the forum as a whole:

```
echo '<form name="SEARCH" id="SEARCH" method="POST" action="orderSamples.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<div class="mainBasketContact">';
echo '<a href="design-search.php"><img src="images/basketLong.png" /></a>';
echo '<p>Enter your details to receive your free samples. Please allow 7 working days for delivery.</p>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">NAME</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input required="required" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" type="text" name="NAME" id="NAME" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">COMPANY</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" type="text" name="COMPANY" id="COMPANY" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">EMAIL</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input required="required" type="email" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">TEL</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input type="number" required style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="TEL" id="TEL" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">PROJECT TITLE</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" type="text" name="PROJECT" id="PROJECT" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
//echo '<div class="contactLabel">ADDRESS</div><div class="contactLabel2"><textarea style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="ADDRESS" id="ADDRESS" /></textarea></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';

echo '<p class="dcHeader1">DELIVERY ADDRESS</p>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">LINE 1</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input required="required" type="text" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="AD1" id="AD1" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">LINE 2</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input type="text" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="AD2" id="AD2" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">TOWN/CITY</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input required="required" type="text" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="TOWN" id="TOWN" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">POSTCODE</div><div class="contactLabel2"><input required="required" type="text" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';" name="POSTCODE" id="POSTCODE" /></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '<div class="contactLabel">FURTHER<br/>NOTES</div><div class="contactLabel2"><textarea name="MESSAGE" id="MESSAGE" style="background:#'.$basketColour.';"></textarea></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';

echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT" />';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div style="clear: both;"></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
```

I've had a fair look around and had no luck so far, if anyone has ANY suggestions please throw them my way! Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the onclick attribute on the form button, which should make it behave the same way as the link you had previously :

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return closeFiveCheck();" />
```

Comment: this nearly works as intended, it causes the javascript to display the "no more than 5 samples" div, but the form still ran, thanks though! I'm past the first hurdle at least!

Comment: Try to return false in the closeFiveCheck function if the check fails